# React pasar datos entre dos componentes no anidados

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un problema, y es que estoy empezando a migrar a react despues de un largo tiempo en vuejs.

Mis problemas principales es la comunicación entre los componentes en vuejs podia utilizar `eventBust` el cual me permitia pasar datos entre componentes que no se encuentran anidados.

actualmente mi proyecto lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
- pageContent
-- topNavBar
-- views
```

Necesito mandar el nombre de la pagina a la `topNavBar` desde un `view`.
He leido que la mejor manera de hacer esto es trabajar con hooks y con clases funcionales. Mi código actual se encuentra de la siguiente manera:

> Mi hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useChangeTitleTopBar(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const change = () => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  };

  return [value, change];
}

export default useChangeTitleTopBar;
```

> TopNavBar

```
import useChangeTitleTopBar from './hooks/useChangeTitleTopBar';
const TheTopNavBar = () => {
const [title] = useChangeTitleTopBar('HelloWorld');
//...
return(
<h1>{title}</h1>
```

Mi pregunta es, como puedo cambiar el titulo desde otro componente y se vea reflejado en mi topNavBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si entendi al 100 tu pregunta, pero pienso que esto te podria funcionar, a tu funcion change le hace falta el parametro con el nuevo titlo, en tu hook estas retornando el valor y tu funcion para cambiar ese valor.

```
function useChangeTitleTopBar(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const change = (newTitle) => {
    setValue(newTitle);
  };

  return [value, change];
}
```

en tu componente `TheTopNavBar`(o cualquiera) ya puedes usar tu hook

```
const TheTopNavBar = () => {
const [title, setTitle] = useChangeTitleTopBar('HelloWorld');

// aqui ya puedes usar setTitle para cambiar el titulo setTitle('otro Titulo')
return(
<h1>{title}</h1>
// ejemplo,
<button onClick={() => setTitle('nuevo titulo')} >click</button>
```